# Visualisation of pool in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to visualise a hierarchy using R shiny.
To select the possible hierarchies, I use the following code in the

ui.R:

```
     sidebarPanel(
selectInput("dataset", "Show the hierarchy of:", 
            choices = c("Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta"))),
```

server.R

```
      datasetInput <- reactive({
          switch(input$dataset,
       "Alfa" = alfa,
       "Beta" = beta,
       "Gamma" = gamma,
       "Delta" = delta)
        })
```

I then need to run the code of hierarchy creation and it includes a code like this:

```
     alfa_top_level_account_id <- account_id_alfa
```

where I need to use the "alfa" as the input from the server.R.
For example if the user choses "Gamma", then the code should run like:

```
     gamma_top_level_account_id <- account_id_gamma
```

etc.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `paste0` to achieve that.

```
paste0(input$dataset,"_top_level_account_id")<-paste0("account_id_",input$dataset)
```

Or if you are using `switch()`:

```
paste0(datasetInput,"_top_level_account_id")<-paste0("account_id_",datasetInput)
```

I hope this help you.